# Access previous state of observable in rxjs

Tags: rxjs

I have state which can take values like - On, dry and off
I have written a selecter to access it from store. 
Basically if state = "dry" , i have to do sometheing. However if state changes from   off to "dry" I am not supposed to perform that action.

Is there some way where i can access the previous value ?

```
export const EnvironmentSelector = createSelector(S1selector, S2selector,
(s1, s2) => {
if (s1=="foo" && s2=== "dry")
    return true;
 else
    return false;
});

this.systemStateEnvironmentSelector$ =this.store.select(EnvironmentSelector);
this.systemStateEnvironmentSelector$.subscribe(val => {
    if (val) {
        //call api()`enter code here`
    }
});
```

Comment: pairwise operator to the rescue

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scan in which you can create a state stack,  with stack[1] as the latest state and stack[0] as previous state. You can then add your conditional logic.

```
this.systemStateEnvironmentSelector$.scan((curr,stack)=>{
  stack.push(curr)
  stack.shift()
  return stack
},[null,null])
..... further conditional operation
.subscribe(console.log)
```